# Continually updating an HTML element from a server file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a site where people can submit comments.  The comments are written to a COMMENTS file on the server. From a separate page, I can then ajax-load the file into a Div and see the comments.

What I would like now is for the Div displaying the comments to be "live". Any new comments coming in while I'm reading the Div would automatically show up at the bottom.

So it looks like I need some kind of a continuously open ajax-load, where the PHP script called continuously monitors the timestamp on the COMMENTS file and copies it again down to the client if the timestamp changes.

I'm wondering if there might be a better way to do this, or if some of it might already be done.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? A really simple solution is just to have a function that uses `$.ajax()` to get the data, and then use `setTimeout()` to call that function again from the ajax success handler 60 seconds later - and repeat...

Comment: You can use ajax continuous or long polling, or you could use server sockets, server sent events, or a "forever frame"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're either going to have to do something very resource intensive or you're going to have to become familiar with tools such as node.js and socket.io for truely live updates.

References:
http://www.nodejs.org
http://www.socket.io
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-node-js-and-websockets-to-build-a-chat-service/

Comment: The key benefit of sockets being that the server can push updates to the client as and when *it* sees fit (ie when a new comment arrives) rather than forcing the client to repeatedly ask the server on the off-chance a new comment may have been added at some point between T and last request.

Comment: Correct, which saves server resources beside the amazingly responsive functionality.

Comment: Never mind server resources! Won't somebody please think of the user? ;)

Comment: @ReQwire, Barney Thanks for the references. I want to do it right. BTW, the other part of this will be to "push" data to the website, something like "John won the contest. He submitted the right answer first." Are there references you can think of, in addition to what are listed above, that would help with that part?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a timer event to check for new comments and publish if updated...

```
timer = setInterval(function() 
    { $.ajax( "getComments.php" )
           .done(function(data) {
                 ("#comments").innerHTML = data;
           })
    }, seconds*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't / don't want to install node.js on your server and implement sockets as @ReQwire suggests, you can reduce the burden on the user slightly by polling a separate resource, something like `/comments?article=articleUID&since=timestamp` (with time stamp being determined by the last timestamp supplied by the server — otherwise you're liable to disparities in time between server and the user's time config), and then append whatever's returned: this service would then look at your `comments` file for that article and only return those comments received after `timestamp`. This reduces the packet weight, such that you will mostly receive an empty response, or at least only new content.